# CursorAdapter crashing app while trying to display listview (with content from database) - logcat inside

Tags: android, database, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

In my application, when clicked, a button "Favorites" is supposed to open a new window with a listview whose content is from a database. I got a NullPointerException when I click this button.

Here is the relevant code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites_list_view);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();        
    displayListView();
}

private void displayListView() {

    c = dbHelper.findFavoritesInTable();
    displayCursor();

}

private void displayCursor() {

    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.FAV_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.FAV_CAT1, DatabaseAdapter.FAV_CAT2,
            DatabaseAdapter.FAV_CAT3, DatabaseAdapter.FAV_CUISINE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.cat1, R.id.cat2, R.id.cat3,
            R.id.cuisine };
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c,
            columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poilistview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        // When we click on elements :
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    POIActivity.class);

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String street = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.street))
                    .getText().toString();
            String website = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website))
                    .getText().toString();
            String telephone = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.telephone)).getText().toString();
            String remarks = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remarks))
                    .getText().toString();
            String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price))
                    .getText().toString();
            String mobile = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cat1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat1))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cat2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat2))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cat3 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat3))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cuisine = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cuisine))
                    .getText().toString();

            i.putExtra(ID_NAME, name);
            i.putExtra(ID_STREET, street);
            i.putExtra(ID_WEBSITE, website);
            i.putExtra(ID_TELEPHONE, telephone);
            i.putExtra(ID_REMARKS, remarks);
            i.putExtra(ID_PRICE, price);
            i.putExtra(ID_MOBILE, mobile);
            i.putExtra(ID_CAT1, cat1);
            i.putExtra(ID_CAT2, cat2);
            i.putExtra(ID_CAT3, cat3);
            i.putExtra(ID_CUISINE, cuisine);

            startActivity(i);
        }

    }); 
}
```

This part of my logcat shows where the problem comes from :
[image]

When I commented out this line, there was no more NPE (but of course nothing was working):

```
listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

What confuses me here is that in this very application, I have another button opening another window with a listview whose content is from another table of the database, and it works well. The code is very similar, I just changed names of the variables.
**So, why can I open my listview and click elements just well in one case, and in this case, I got a NPE with a similar code ?!** I have no idea where it can come from, maybe the table from my database?  Thanks for your help, I am really struggling here.
**EDIT :** Here is the full logcat :

```
04-12 11:45:03.779: W/dalvikvm(2998): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a95390)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asiatypeapplicationbeta/com.example.asiatypeapplicationbeta.FavoritesListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1964)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1155)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.example.asiatypeapplicationbeta.FavoritesListView.displayCursor(FavoritesListView.java:62)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.example.asiatypeapplicationbeta.FavoritesListView.displayListView(FavoritesListView.java:46)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.example.asiatypeapplicationbeta.FavoritesListView.onCreate(FavoritesListView.java:40)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
04-12 11:45:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     ... 11 more
```

My DatabaseAdapter.class :

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

public static final String DATABASE_POITABLE = "tblpoisurvey";
public static final String DATABASE_FAVTABLE = "tblfavorites";

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String POI_NAME = "name";
public static final String POI_CAT1 = "cat1";
public static final String POI_CAT2 = "cat2";
public static final String POI_CAT3 = "cat3";
public static final String POI_SUBCAT = "subcat";
public static final String POI_STREET = "street";
public static final String POI_WEBSITE = "website";
public static final String POI_REMARKS = "remarks";
public static final String POI_TELEPHONE = "telephoneNo";
public static final String POI_MOBILE = "mobileNo";
public static final String POI_PRICE = "priceLevel";
public static final String POI_DATEFRIENDLY = "dateFriendly";
public static final String POI_PAYMENT = "paymentOptions";
public static final String POI_CUISINE = "cuisine";
// public static final String COL_X = "x";
// public static final String COL_Y = "y";

public static final String FAV_ID = "_id";
public static final String FAV_NAME = "name";
public static final String FAV_CAT1 = "cat1";
public static final String FAV_CAT2 = "cat2";
public static final String FAV_CAT3 = "cat3";
public static final String FAV_STREET = "street";
public static final String FAV_WEBSITE = "website";
public static final String FAV_REMARKS = "remarks";
public static final String FAV_TELEPHONE = "telephoneNo";
public static final String FAV_MOBILE = "mobileNo";
public static final String FAV_PRICE = "priceLevel";
public static final String FAV_DATEFRIENDLY = "dateFriendly";
public static final String FAV_PAYMENT = "paymentOptions";
public static final String FAV_CUISINE = "cuisine";

private Context myContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private Cursor c;

// Constructor
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.myContext = context;
}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(myContext);
    try {
        dbHelper.createDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
    try {
        dbHelper.close();
        myDatabase.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Method findPoiInTable, called when the user clicks on a level2 icon
// button to open the listview
public Cursor findPoiInTable(String categoryInterval) {
    String where = POI_CAT1 + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + POI_CAT2
            + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + POI_CAT3 + " IN "
            + categoryInterval;

    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_POITABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, POI_NAME, POI_STREET, POI_WEBSITE, POI_PAYMENT,
            POI_TELEPHONE, POI_PRICE, POI_REMARKS, POI_DATEFRIENDLY,
            POI_MOBILE, POI_CAT1, POI_CAT2, POI_CAT3, POI_CUISINE }, where,
            null, null, null, POI_NAME);
    return c;
}

public Cursor findFavoritesInTable() {

    Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("select * from tblfavorites",null);
    return c;
}

public static long insertInTable(String ID_NAME, String ID_CAT1,
        String ID_CAT2, String ID_CAT3, String ID_CUISINE) {
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    data.put(FAV_NAME, ID_NAME);
    data.put(FAV_CAT1, ID_CAT1);
    data.put(FAV_CAT2, ID_CAT2);
    data.put(FAV_CAT3, ID_CAT3);
    data.put(FAV_CUISINE, ID_CUISINE);
    if (myDatabase == null) {

    }
    return myDatabase.insert("DATABASE_FAVTABLE", "nullColumnHack", data);
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your logcat. The screenshot is too small to read on my end.

Comment: Also, which line of code causes the NPE? (Check your logcat and indicate in your question which one it is.)

Comment: @Code-Guru : done editing, the whole logcat is at the bottom of the message now !

Comment: So the NPE occurs on line 62 of FavoritesListView.java. Which line of code is this?

Comment: @Code-Guru : it is this one " listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter); "

Comment: You should check to see why `listView` is null.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand, all the code for the listview content is here, and it's basically the same as for another part of my application... but it crashes. I still too much of a beginner for understanding where it exactly comes from. Could it be because the table of my database is empty ?

Comment: Most likely you have not correctly initialized the `listView` variable which you are using on line 62 of FavoritesListView.java. You should use a debugger or add `System.out.println()` statements to verify this and work backwards from there to find out why `listView` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

try this way.

```
  //check DatabaseAdapter is your database name with single parameter constructor
    DatabaseAdapter DdbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
     dbHelper.open();  
     Cursor c = dbHelper.findFavoritesInTable();
     if(c.getCount()!=0){
         System.out.println("CURSOR VALUE:"+c.getCount());
         displayCursor();
     }
     c.close();
     dbHelper.close();
    }
```

You can first find if cursor value is not null then your `displayCursor()` is call.

If you are not getting solution then put comment.

Comment: Thanks for this @Harshid but it still crashes with what appear to be the same logcat as before. :(
I also tried to comment out "displayCursor()", then it opens the new activiy with an empty view.

Comment: see my updated answer.if you not getting solution please give me DatabaseAdapter.class file.

Comment: Thanks @Harshid : it actually helps a bit to add this, as it keeps from problems to happen in regard of other function calling the same database. Unfortunately, I still have the mistake related to the cursoradapter in my displayCursor(). When "displayCursor()" is commented out it's ok, otherwise... I'm editing my first message to give my databaseAdapter class !

Comment: I can upgrade your answer and I did as it provides with useful information but the main problem isn't solved yet, I still have the same crash and the same logcat as initially, related to my simpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: please give me System.out.println("CURSOR VALUE:"+c.getCount()); value and put displayCursor() in comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28081/discussion-between-harshid-and-phalanx)